# Link existing social media accounts to drupal account

Tags: 7, users

Both upon registration and/or user editing later on, how could one give the user the ability to link his acccount with a plethora of social networks such as Facebook, LinkedIn, Skype, Google+, Twitter, etc?

I am not looking for an oAuth solution to (just) log in or register with one of the afforementioned accounts instead of a standart drupal one, I am looking for a way to give the user the ability to log in and/or register with either one of those accounts.

Is that technically possible? If yes, is there a one-in-all solution modulewise?

EDIT: to give some extra clarity, the ability to link your social networks' account(s) is a requirement upon *registration* too. Something like a "field-like" behaviour that will somehow store the connection with the social network account. Kinda blunt but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for [this](http://drupal.org/project/rpx) module. It supports many providers for register and login integration.

Basic version is free. More details check below link!

http://janrain.com/products/engage/engage-pricing/

Comment: Seems good, but I am not sure if 2.5k user per year will work for me and/or the client will go for a subscription, will have it in mind though. Thanks.